# Python - Splitting multiple columns by delimiter

Tags: python, join, pandas, split

Note: I'm a beginner with Python and just started using Pandas a couple days ago.  I have a background in R.

I'm trying to split a pandas DataFrame, but can only seem to split one column at a time by one delimiter at a time.

My data looks like this:

```
                          0         1             2            3  \
0    chr4:43571332-43571643  numsnp=3    length=312  state1,cn=0   
1  chr5:179618873-179628421  numsnp=8  length=9,549  state1,cn=0   

                  4                 5               6  
0  CCCC.A_1_TR27GD1  startsnp=S-3TZTE  endsnp=S-4NDOX  
1  CCCC.A_1_TR27GD1  startsnp=S-3IDBJ  endsnp=S-4AKVJ
```

I want my output to look like this:

```
  Chromosome      Start        End NumSNP Length StartSNP   EndSNP
0          4   43571332   43571643      3    312  S-3TZTE  S-4NDOX
1          5  179618873  179628421      8  9,549  S-3IDBJ  S-4AKVJ
```

I know this is a lot, but this involves the following:

- Split column 0 by : and -....also removing the "chr"
- Split columns 1,2,5,6
- Rename & reorder columns
- etc

**QUESTION:**
I've been able to do it using the code below, but would like some guidance into a more efficient code.

```
import pandas as pd

CNV = pd.read_csv('CCCC_cnv_practice.rawcnv', delimiter="\s+", engine='python', header=None)

#Get Chromosomes
ChrPos = pd.DataFrame(CNV[0].str.split(':',1).tolist(), columns = ['Chromosome','Position'])
Chromosome = ChrPos['Chromosome'].str.lstrip('chr')

#Get Start and End Positions
Positions = pd.DataFrame(ChrPos.Position.str.split('-',1).tolist(), columns = ['Start','End'])

#Get the Numsnp, Length, StartSNP, and EndSNP columns
Equals1 = CNV.iloc[:,1:3]
Equals2 = CNV.iloc[:,5:]
Equals = Equals1.join(Equals2)

TEST1 = pd.DataFrame(Equals[1].str.split('=',1).tolist())
TEST2 = pd.DataFrame(Equals[2].str.split('=',1).tolist())
TEST3 = pd.DataFrame(Equals[5].str.split('=',1).tolist())
TEST4 = pd.DataFrame(Equals[6].str.split('=',1).tolist())

#Put it all together
frames = [Chromosome, Positions, TEST1[1], TEST2[1], TEST3[1], TEST4[1]]
Data = pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
Data.columns = ['Chromosome', 'Start', 'End', 'NumSNP', 'Length', 'StartSNP', 'EndSNP']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
print df
                          0         1             2            3  \
0    chr4:43571332-43571643  numsnp=3    length=312  state1,cn=0   
1  chr5:179618873-179628421  numsnp=8  length=9,549  state1,cn=0   

                  4                 5               6  
0  CCCC.A_1_TR27GD1  startsnp=S-3TZTE  endsnp=S-4NDOX  
1  CCCC.A_1_TR27GD1  startsnp=S-3IDBJ  endsnp=S-4AKVJ  

#new empty dataframe    
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1[['Chromosome', 'tmp']] = pd.DataFrame([ x.split(':') for x in df[0].tolist() ])
df1[['Start', 'End']] = pd.DataFrame([ x.split('-') for x in df1['tmp'].tolist() ])

#tmp is temporary column   
df1[['tmp', 'NumSNP']]   = pd.DataFrame([ x.split('=') for x in df[1].tolist() ])
df1[['tmp', 'Length']]   = pd.DataFrame([ x.split('=') for x in df[2].tolist() ])
df1[['tmp', 'StartSNP']] = pd.DataFrame([ x.split('=') for x in df[5].tolist() ])
df1[['tmp', 'EndSNP']]   = pd.DataFrame([ x.split('=') for x in df[6].tolist() ])

df1['Chromosome'] = df1['Chromosome'].str.lstrip('chr')

#delete tmp column    
df1 = df1.drop(['tmp'], axis=1)
print df1

#  Chromosome      Start        End NumSNP Length StartSNP   EndSNP
#0          4   43571332   43571643      3    312  S-3TZTE  S-4NDOX
#1          5  179618873  179628421      8  9,549  S-3IDBJ  S-4AKVJ
```

Comment: This drops my code from 14 lines to 10.  Thank you.  There is no way to do the 4 lines after `#tmp is temporary column ` in 1 step (i.e. split all columns by `'='`)?

Comment: I think it is not possible, because you works with `Series.string`. How is length of dataframe - `print len(df)`? Is huge?

Comment: The largest dataframe has 180,000 rows.